# Roblox Studio (LUA) - Saving Table to DataStore (Not Working)

Tags: lua, datastore, roblox

I have been trying multiple ways to save two values to a DataStore whilst using pcall for error handling, and I cannot seem to figure out a solution to make my code work.

Any suggestion on changes?

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

local myDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("myDataStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local cash = Instance.new("IntValue")
    cash.Name = "Cash"
    cash.Parent = leaderstats

    local wins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    wins.Name = "Wins"
    wins.Parent = leaderstats

    local data
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        data = myDataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-user")
    end)

    if success then
        cash.Value = data[1] or 0
        wins.Value = data[2] or 0
    else
        print("There was an error while fetching your data.")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        myDataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-user", {player.leaderstats.Cash.Value, player.leaderstats.Wins.Value})
    end)

    if success then
        print("Player data successfully saved.")
    else
        print("There was an error saving your data.")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)
```

Comment: Heyo dharrison, when trying to figure out what's going wrong, saying "It doesn't work" generally isn't helpful. I see you've added a bunch of print statements already, are you seeing any of them show up in the Output window when you test in Studio?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info there... So, I THINK I have it solved. At least, for now. The end result I had with this code was that it wasn't saving the values when the player left the game. But, I was testing this code in the Studio. When I switched the Studio Mode to Server, from Client, it seems to work fine.